# Comparison between service worker and AppCache

Tags: html5-appcache, service-worker

What are the core differences between service worker and AppCache. What are the pros and cons of each and when to prefer one over another .

Answer (score 28):

The primary difference is that AppCache is a high-level, declarative API, with which you specify the set of resources you'd like the browser to cache; whereas Service Worker is a low-level, imperative, event-driven API with which you write a script that can intercept fetch events and cache their responses along with doing other things (like displaying push notifications).

The pros and cons are largely a function of API design: theoretically, AppCache is easier to use, while having more limited use cases; whereas Service Worker is harder to use, but is more flexible.

Nevertheless, AppCache is considered hard to use in practice due to poor design (see [Application Cache Is A Douchebag](http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag) for a list of design issues).  And it has been deprecated, so it is being removed from browsers (per [Using the application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)).

Thus the only reason to prefer AppCache is to offline an app on browsers that don't yet support Service Worker, as Kenneth Ormandy recommends in [Don’t Wait for ServiceWorker: Adding Offline Support with One-Line](https://davidwalsh.name/dont-wait-serviceworker-adding-offline-support-oneline).

Compare [Can I use Service Workers?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers) to [Can I use Offline web applications?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps) to see the differences in browser support. But note that browsers that support Service Worker, like Chrome and Firefox, are removing support for AppCache, so you'll need to implement both to offline your app across all browsers that support either standard.

Answer (score 7):

In addition of what [Myk Melez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36043081/1342491) said, One of the main benefits of Service Workers against Application Cache is that Application Cache only works when user is disconnected from the network, so you can not manage situations of:

1- "slow network" - Your connection signal is strong, however some external entities (server, routes, etc) are delaying the transmission to your specific application.

2- "Lie-fi" (your phone shows is connected to a wi-fi or a cell network with low signal) so it seems to be connected when actually is not.

Service Workers is like a middle ware giving you control over the requests the browser is making, you can actually intercept the request and respond wherever you want, no matter you are connected or not. So you can implement "offline first" principle.